# Solidity different token price

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm just checking the Solidity code for my school project.
I have a questions about this code:

`price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;`

Can I add something like:

*(if they send more then 2 ether they have a bonus like the maximum 5000)*

```
 If (ether contribution > 2 ether) {
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, 5000);
    }else{
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    }
```

Is this possible?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal; uint public amountRaised; uint public deadline; uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    /* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () payable {
        if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find my bellow answer correct and helpful? if yes, please mark as answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by modifying your `payable` method to be something like:

```
//You can add a constant to save the bonus amount:
uint constant bonus = 5000;

//Inside this method check if amount is larger than 2:
function () payable {
    if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    if (amount > 2) {
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price + bonus);
    } else {
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    }
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}
```